# How to setup spacy behind firewall

Tags: python, spacy

I am behind a firewall and would like to use spacy (version 2.2.4) for gernan language like explained at https://explosion.ai/blog/german-model. The recomended way is not possible:

```
python -m spacy download de
```

What I did:

Download:

```
@wget https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz
@wget https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/de_core_news_sm-2.2.5/de_core_news_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz
@wget https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/de_core_news_md-2.2.5/de_core_news_md-2.2.5.tar.gz
```

Install:

```
pip install en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz
pip install de_core_news_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz
pip install de_core_news_md-2.2.5.tar.gz
```

In Spyder I can't load 'en' or 'de'.
I can load the english model by name.
I can't load the german models by name.

```
import spacy

#de = spacy.load('de')
#OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'de'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

en = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
print(en.Defaults.stop_words)

#de = spacy.load('en')
#OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

#de = spacy.load('de_core_news_md')
#OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'de_core_news_md'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

#de = spacy.load('de_core_news_sm')
#OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'de_core_news_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

There is a stop_words.py under

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spacy\lang\de
```

Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of Spacy have you installed? Also, could you try "import de_core_news_md
; de = de_core_news_md.load() and see if you get an import error?

Comment: print(spacy.__version__) says 2.2.4. load() does not do anything. No error no nothing - just no reaction.

Comment: So, for me what you did works smoothly (same spacy updated version), maybe something went wrong in the installation, are the model installed in the correct environment inside 'site-packages'? I think so since you don't have an import error when trying to import the model directly, but checking doesn't hurt. Also, you might consider to open an issue in GitHub, I saw that many people have similar issues when trying to install new language models. Sorry I can't help you more than this, it's hard when you can't reproduce the error.

Comment: "pip list" shows correct entries. So I tried again: "pip uninstall de_core_news_sm" no error. "pip install de_core_news_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz" -> Successfully installed de-core-news-sm-2.2.5. Python load(model): same error: Can't find model...

Comment: It does work after creating a symlink from the model to 'de'. I don't know why 'de' should be a better name than the name of the model - but anyway after "python -m spacy link de_core_news_sm de" the model can be used. To change the model you need to --force the creation of the link, i.e. "python -m spacy link de_core_news_md de --force". Strange architecture!!!